# connection from my program to the server using XAMPP server and actionscript program in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, connection, xampp

i have the following code ]

```
connection.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF0;
connection.connect("http://localhost/test/test.php"); 

var responder = new Responder(recvdata,recverror);
connection.call("test.test",responder);
```

but no connection established what is the reason behind not know help required and one more thing XAMPP is installed in D:\ drive.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got the problem

```
connection.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
connection.connect("http://localhost/flashservices/gateway.php"); 

var responder = new Responder(recvdata,recverror);
connection.call("test.test",responder);
```

this works for me and don't forget to add AMFPHP on server root folder.